# Activity lifecycle vs View lifecycle: how to avoid NPE?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, nullpointerexception, lifecycle

I have a `ListView` which adapts data from a cursor. The cursor's position of the record is stored via `View.setTag()`, so it can be retrieved in response to user events.

```
public class OrderActivity extends Activity {

  private ListView list;
  private CursorAdapter adapter;
  private SQLiteDatabase database;

  public void onResume() {
    database = new Database(this).getWriteableDatabase();
    // query the db and store the position of the cursor
    // as the tag while binding the view in the overridden
    // CursorAdapter.bindView()
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( /* code here */ );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  public void onPause() {
    adapter.changeCursor(null);
    database.close();
  }

  private void onClickRowDumpOrder(View row) {
    int newPosition = (Integer) row.getTag();
    Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();
    int originalPosition = cursor.getPosition(); // Throws NPE

    cursor.moveToPosition(newPosition);
    Log.v("tag", "Description: " + cursor.getString(0));

    // restore the cursor
    cursor.moveToPosition(originalPosition);
  }

}
```

I store the database and the adapter in instance fields of my Activity to allocate/free resources during the activity lifecycle: I create a new database `onResume` and close it `onPause`. Unfortunately, I receive lots of reports from my users that a NPE is thrown in the line outlined in the pseudocode above, but I'm not able to reproduce it.

It seems that `cursor` is `null`, but I wonder how this is possible if the method `onClickRowDumpOrder` can only be called after `onResume`, since it's the callback to the click event (I set this in the XML layout via `android:onClick`)

Am I doing something wrong? What API misusage causes the `cursor` to be null? Is there some documentation describing how cursors and adapters are intended to fit in the activity lifecycle?

**UPDATE**

I got rid of `android:onClick` in my XML file and manually set the listener inside `SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView`. To avoid leaks, I remove the listener either in my custom [`AbsListView.RecycleListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setRecyclerListener%28android.widget.AbsListView.RecyclerListener%29) and in my activity's `onPause` (I retrieve all views with [`reclaimViews(List<View>)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#reclaimViews%28java.util.List%3Candroid.view.View%3E%29)). This seems to fix the bug, and here is my explanation.

1. A new View is inflated when my activity first starts
2. instance#1 of my activity is set as the OnClickListener for that particular View in the View's constructor, when it parses the `android:onClick` attribute
3. instance#1 leaves the foreground, thus onPause() sets the cursor to null. Note that this activity is still the listener for the View, because neither the view nor the activity are marked for garbage collection. This means that they are referenced in some cache in the Android classes
4. instance#2 of my activity is created, and its list view somewhat **recycle** the already created View. The data is shown correctly, but this view still has the old activity (with a null cursor) as the listener
5. when user clicks my view, instance#1 handler is called, but it has a null cursor. This causes the NPE

This explanation is realistic, however I didn't find relevant code in Android classes (there is a cache in `AbsListView.RecycleBin`, but the ListView itself is not reused). Moreover, I've never been able to reproduce this bug, and I solely think my fix works because in the last two days I received no reports (usually I get a few dozens a day)

Are you aware of any code in the Android stack which can validate my assumptions?

Comment: So can you rotate the phone quickly between portrait/landscape a number of times without a NPE?

Comment: Yes, anyway this is not relevant to my app since it only allows portrait mode, so when the user rotates the device the activity isn't destroyed

Comment: Please post the code you are using to create the cursor

Comment: The cursor is created inside the `new SimpleCursorAdapter` with a standard `mSQLiteDatabase.query(...)` and is not relevant. See the update

Comment: Why do you need a writable database for this list?

Comment: @Sparky items can be edited and removed from the list, but what's that got to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way.
`if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
}
}`

Comment: My problem is that the cursor is null inside onClickRow

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating the cursor at the wrong point in the Activity lifecycle.  The [ListView sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) puts in `onCreate()` what you have in `onResume()`.  I don't know that it's necessarily harmful, but you may be recreating some things that don't need to be.

Comment: This would be an optimization, but what has to do with the question? Sure, if I don't unset the cursor `onPause` it won't trigger the NPE, but it's the **wrong fix**. If you read carefully my question (especially the update with my own fix) it seems that the old activity is leaked as the listener when you use `android:onClick`. I think you should investigate this and tell if/why my fix works, but your suggestion would only hyde the error. Unfortunately I don't have a reproducible case to give you :(